# Django Queryset Count

Tags: python, django, count, django-queryset

My model:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    build = models.CharField()
    name = models.CharField()
```

How do I build my queryset so I can get the count of objects with different builds.

For example if there were two builds 'build 1' and 'build 2', I would want an output that would tell me

```
build 1 = 3
build 2 = 4
```

EDIT: Tried the following:

```
Device.objects.values('build').annotate(count=Count('pk'))
```

the output is:

```
[{'build': u'wed build'}, {'build': u'red build'}, ... ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you want a **single** queryset that can output that?

Comment: Just want an efficient way of doing it really. I can iterate over builds and get the counts but I wanted to see if there was a better way to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Count

Device.objects.values('build').annotate(count=Count('pk'))
# -> [{'build': '1', 'count': 3}, {'build': '2', 'count': 4}]
```

Comment: Of course it should. I wouldn't be surprised at all for a mongo-django mapper to not support annotations. You'll have to use MapReduce or iterate over builds and get counts.

Answer (score 4):

A simple approach is just calling [`count`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#count):

```
>>> Device.objects.filter(build='1').count()
3
>>> Device.objects.filter(build='2').count()
4
```